# How do I create a local folder in my computer using simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning to create a web app like thing in which i need to create a permanent folder in local disk of client system.so how can this be done using a simple javascript code.
It needs to be platform and browser independent ,are there any alternative to ActiveX Objects which works with IE.

Comment: The only possibilities of saving content to client computer with js are localStorage and cookies as I know.

Comment: One of solution is chrome extensions ( or browser  plugin)...